# Finding out the name of a Window

Tags: linux, gnome, suse

Is there a way to determine the name of a program that keeps popping up dialog boxes within Gnome?

When I reboot my SUSE Linux machine, after I log in I am constantly bombarded with pop-up dialogs with the title 'Software signature is required' and asking 'Do you trust the source of the packages?'  It looks to be related to yum, but I"m not sure.

If I click cancel it will just pop-up again a few minutes later.  If I press OK it just sits there spinning.  Ultimately I'd like to get to the bottom of what is causing this pop-up, but for now I'd like to find out what program is causing this window to pop-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xwininfo` to grab the window's ID and the ID of it's parent/children. Type `xwininfo -children` at the command line then click the window in question.

To find which application is it's parent from the ID, run `xwininfo -root -children`. You will see also children of the root window (X). Look (or grep) through the ID's to see which one was the parent that spawned the dialog box.

Comment: Turns out the little devil was PackageKit!